# Rails Validations with Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, redis

I have a bunch of Redis getters and setters like

```
def share_points= p
  $redis.set("store:#{self.id}:points:share", p) if valid?
end
```

The thing is, ActiveRecord's validation doesn't stop the values from being inserted into redis. How do I go about doing this without adding `if valid?` on every setter? `valid?` calculates the validation every time it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about switching to an `after_save` callback approach, where you store all the fields that have been changed and just persist them all at once to redis.

Something like:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_save :persist_to_redis
  attr_accessor :redis_attributes

  def share_points=(p)
    @redis_attributes ||= {}
    @redis_attributes[:share_points] = p
  end

  def something_else=(p)
    @redis_attributes ||= {}
    @redis_attributes[:something_else] = p
  end

  private

  def redis_store_share_points(value)
    $redis.set("store:#{self.id}:key", value)
  end


  def redis_store_something_else(value)
    $redis.set("something_else:#{self.id}", value)
  end

  def persist_to_redis
    $redis.multi do
      @redis_attributes.each_pair do |key, value|
        send("redis_store_#{key}".to_sym, value)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I think even this could be refactored and cleaned up but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you. That's the solution I came up with today, with a few minor changes. Is multi faster than doing it one by one?

Comment: You're still doing it one by one but `multi` can enable the client to pipeline the requests and do them as part of a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

If the model you're editing is derived from active_record, then you probably want to have a specific, wrapped call to redis that does the validation for you. e.g.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def rset(key,value)
    $redis.set("store:#{self.id}:key", value) if valid?
  end
  def share_points=(p)
     rset("points:share", p)
  end
end
```

You could also put that in a module and include it.

If you're not deriving from AR:Base, you might want to come up with a more AR::Base-like structure using ActiveModel as described here: http://purevirtual.de/2010/04/url-shortener-with-redis-and-rails3/

Comment: Oh, and I guess another thing you could do is monkey-patch some aliasing on $redis.set, but that would affect all the calls to $redis.set, so it might not be appropriate

Comment: I'm using MongoDB (mongoid) with Redis on the same model. the problem with using valid? is that it runs all the model validations every time it's called (source code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb). If I update 4 redis properties it will run the validation 5 times.

Comment: If the validations aren't expensive to compute, does it matter?

Comment: IIRC, mongoid has after_save callbacks, so you could use mset (redis.io/commands/mset) instead of set in one of those.

Comment: how do I pass the values to mset? I mean, update_attributes calls key(value) on the model (e.g. share_points(100), with params[:store][:share_points]), so how do I access all this values?

Comment: You'd need to have a list somewhere of the params that were redis v. mongo-based. Here's a gist (assuming mset takes a hash…): https://gist.github.com/c9d4b0e4c016a72beec6  I'm not sure this is a great idea, since it involves overriding update_attributes, but I think it would do the job.